# Dask Dataframe: Defining meta for date diff in groubpy

Tags: pandas, datetime, pandas-groupby, dask

I'm trying to find inter-purchase times (i.e., days between orders) for customers. Although my code is working correctly without defining `meta`, I would like to get it working properly and no longer see the warning asking me to provide `meta`.

Also, I would appreciate any suggestions on how to use `map` or `map_partitions` instead of `apply`.

So far I've tried:

- `meta={'days_since_last_order': 'datetime64[ns]'}`
- `meta={'days_since_last_order': 'f8'}`
- `meta={'ORDER_DATE_DT':'datetime64[ns]','days_since_last_order': 'datetime64[ns]'}`
- `meta={'ORDER_DATE_DT':'f8','days_since_last_order': 'f8'}`
- `meta=('days_since_last_order', 'f8')`
- `meta=('days_since_last_order', 'datetime64[ns]')`

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import datetime as dt
import dask.dataframe as dd
from dask.distributed import wait, Client

client = Client(processes=True)

start = pd.to_datetime('2015-01-01')
end = pd.to_datetime('2018-01-01')
d = (end - start).days + 1

np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['CUSTOMER_ID'] = np.random.randint(1, 4, 10)
df['ORDER_DATE_DT'] = start + pd.to_timedelta(np.random.randint(1, d, 10), unit='d')
print(df.sort_values(['CUSTOMER_ID','ORDER_DATE_DT']))
print(df)

ddf = dd.from_pandas(df, npartitions=2)

# setting ORDER_DATE_DT as index to sort by date
ddf = ddf.set_index('ORDER_DATE_DT')
ddf = client.persist(ddf)
wait(ddf)

ddf = ddf.reset_index()
grp = ddf.groupby('CUSTOMER_ID')[['ORDER_DATE_DT']].apply(
    lambda df: df.assign(days_since_last_order=df.ORDER_DATE_DT.diff(1))
    # meta=????
)

# for some reason, I'm unable to print grp unless I reset_index()
grp = grp.reset_index()
print(grp.compute())
```

Here is the printout of `df.sort_values(['CUSTOMER_ID','ORDER_DATE_DT'])`

[image]

Here is the printout of `grp.compute()`

[image]

Comment: I'm probably not going to dive into this one just because it's somewhat long, but I thought you'd like to know that this inspired this patch to help solve the problem more generally.  https://github.com/dask/dask/pull/4637